# How do I adjust an ion-checkbox's height and width?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a checkbox component build with `ion-checkbox`:

```
selector: 'app-checkbox',
  template: `
      <div class="app-checkbox">
          <ion-item class="-DARKMODE"
                    lines="none">
              <ion-checkbox [checked]="checked"
                            (ionChange)="onCheckChanged($event)"></ion-checkbox>
              <span>{{label}}</span>
          </ion-item>
      </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app-checkbox.scss'],
```

and this is the scss:

```
.app-checkbox {

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: center;

  ion-item {
    --padding-start: 0;
  }

  ion-checkbox {
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
  }

  span {
    @include body-small;
    margin-left: $padding-single;
  }
}
```

I've been trying to change the height and width of the ion-checkbox but nothing seems to work. I've even tried

```
--width: 26px;
--height: 26px;
```

I've tried using `--size:` but it's not achieving what I need. I would need to specifically change the SVG's size but even doing

```
ion-checkbox {
  svg {
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
  }
}
```

nested under ion-checkbox doesn't work. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

When you see in the developer console, do you see the css is effective ? Its very much possible, the other defined style in your project is taking the precedence. Try using the style force override using `!important` tag, it should solve your problem.

There is nothing wrong with how you are setting the style for ion-checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue with being unable to change padding on `ion-checkbox` or change the height of `svg` inside of it in any way. I ended up using a transparent border as a quick solution.

```
--border-width: 6px;
--border-color: transparent;
```

You can also make all backgrounds on `ion-checkbox` transparent and create a custom wrapper around it with padding and ripple effect if you want a custom solution.